# Getter function to return values of a struct in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm practicing c and I want to return data of a struct to access it within an other location.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int8    x;    
    u64     y;     
    u32     z;   
} myData_t;


myData_t myData_g;


/*Setter*/
void WritemyData(const myData_t* data)
{
    myData_g = *data;
}
```

How can I return the data which are stored within a global variable to be read within an other location. Can I not just do something like:

```
/*Getter*/
myData_t GettmyData(void)
{
    return myData_g;
}
```

Would be thankful for any information!

Comment: Your `GettmyData` should work fine to query the data. But it returns a copy. you could also return a `const myData_t*` (with `return &myData_g`).

Comment: Please note that your struct layout is very poor and will create needless padding bytes for nothing. You should move the `x` member to the bottom of the struct list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for things like this consider making the "global" a private variable instead, by adding `static myData_t myData_g;`. Now nobody outside this .c file can access it intentionally/by accident.

As for your function `GettmyData`, it will work fine. However, passing/returning structs by value is considered bad practice since it involves making a full copy of the struct on the stack, which may be slow and take up unnecessary memory temporarily.

This might be better idea might be:

```
void get_my_data (myData_t* obj)
{
  *obj = myData_g;
}
```

Here you have to document that the caller should allocate the variable pointed at by `obj` on the caller side.